# Using a VTK box widgets transform to rotate a non-vtk 3D model?

Tags: c++, 3d, transformation, vtk

I'm using vtk to visualize 3D models of molecules.
The actual molecular model is decoupled from vtk code, and visualization is implemented using a model-view kind of design.

Currently I have the following challenge. If a user wants to manipulate the absolute orientation of the molecule, it is done by manipulating the underlying model using rotation functions, like RotateX, RotateY, RotateAboutVector, and translation functions TranslateX, Y etc.

For now 3D rotations are simply done using two scrollbars, one horizontal and one vertical, causing the underlying model being rotated about the vtk viewUP vector and the vtk cameraPlane normal respectively.  This works fine, but is not so intuitive for the user.

Instead I believe allowing interaction with something like a box widget that encapsulates the molecule view, (with disabled handles), would be better.

The challenge is how to figure out how to capture the boxwidgets orientation in a callback, and using this information in order to manipulate the underlying molecular model.

For example, a boxwidget callback (from boxwidget example at http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Widgets/BoxWidget):

```
class vtkMyCallback : public vtkCommand
{
    public:
    static vtkMyCallback *New()       {            return new vtkMyCallback;        }

virtual void Execute(vtkObject *caller, unsigned long, void*)
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> t =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
    vtkBoxWidget *widget = reinterpret_cast<vtkBoxWidget*>(caller);
    widget->GetTransform(t);

    double* angles?? = t->GetOrientation(); 
    if(aMoleculeModel)
    {
        //Use some secret(!) code to manipulate orientation of a molecule to 'rotate' it together with the boxWidget
        aMoleculeModel->RotateZ(??);
        aMoleculeModel->RotateY(??);
        aMoleculeModel->RotateZ(??);
    }
}
Molecule* aMoleculeModel;
```

Anyone seeing how to do this or have some pointers?

Cheers,
tk

Comment: Is it necessary to call the rotate methods of the model, or it's possible to make the trasnformation only in the visualization part? If the latter, have you considered trying one of the available interactors http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/StyleSwitch ?

Comment: I am using derived interactor classes, but that is not related to the problem, as I see it. It is crucial that the rotations are applied on the underlying model, and manifested in the viewing part.